# AWS IAM Polciy to allow billing contact modification

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

I have the following policy assigned to an IAM user which gives full permission to the billing.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "aws-portal:*Billing",
                "awsbillingconsole:*Billing",
                "aws-portal:*Usage",
                "awsbillingconsole:*Usage",
                "aws-portal:*PaymentMethods",
                "awsbillingconsole:*PaymentMethods",
                "budgets:ViewBudget",
                "budgets:ModifyBudget",
                "cur:*",
                "purchase-orders:*PurchaseOrders"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

This policy does not allow the user to modify the alternate billing contact. The alternative billing contact settings is found under the `https://console.aws.amazon.com/billing/home?#/account`. Is there anyway to achieve this without giving administrator permissions.

Answer (score 1):

Try granting all `aws-portal` actions

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "aws-portal:*",
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: will this permission allow the user to close the aws account. because closing the aws account is in the billing account page.

Comment: @arun k You could reduce the scope of the actions allowed on the portal resource See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/list_awsbilling.html

Comment: Only the root user can close an AWS account: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/root-vs-iam.html